# display text from user on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, text, canvas

Now I have 3 Elements. a textfield and a submit button are on top and under them is a canvas. I want to display the input from user on canvas after clicking submit button.

I'm glad to see any javascript suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Only because I like working with canvas so much.. this should get you started. For future reference make sure to post what you've tried when asking a question, generally people don't like supplying full solutions to vague problems.

```
var btn = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0],
    textArea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0],
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = 512;

    ctx.font = "12px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";

    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        ctx.fillText(textArea.value,10,10);
    });
​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B3ntY/1/)**